Borrowchecker not allowing another borrow in loop due to return lifetime constraint
I am writing a reader that looks up a string in some table and returns a string with some the same lifetime as the table used to look up the information in. A minimal (not) working example is:
struct LookupTable {}
    
trait Reader {
    fn read<'a>(&mut self, lookup: &'a mut LookupTable) -> Option<&'a str>;
}

fn not_working<'a>(mut reader: impl Reader, lookup: &'a mut LookupTable) -> Option<&'a str> {
    loop {
        let opt = reader.read(lookup);
        if let Some(s) = opt {
            return Some(s);
        }
        drop(opt);
    }
}

The compiler says: "cannot borrow *lookup as mutable more than once at a time*lookup was mutably borrowed here in the previous iteration of the loop"
If I replace the return by todo!() everything works just fine.
I do not know why the compiler does not let me borrow lookup again, since the return value opt was dropped before the next iteration. I would expect the compiler to infer that opt can no longer be alive in the next iteration (especially because we call drop explicitly before entering the next iteration).
